# Usando quebra de linha "\n" no Java

Tags: java

Que problema um programador Java pode ter ao usar `"\n"` para pular linha?

**Observação:** Já utilizei ele por N motivos, gravar um arquivo `TXT` e outros.

Comment: Você quis dizer `"\n"`? Além disso a pergunta não está nem um pouco objetiva no formato atual. Seria fechável como amplo demais.

Comment: Bom, talvez parece ser um pergunta sem objetivo, mas com Java é multiplataforma, quero saber sem em outros sistemas isso causaria problema.

Comment: Amigo acho que você deveria simplificar seu nome para Eduardobrj

Comment: Obrigado pela dica amigo, farei isso dia 19/03, se tiver mais sugestões me mande.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

O único problema é que se seu arquivo for aberto no Windows (ou Mac), alguns editores de texto não vão reconhecer a quebra de linha e mostrar tudo como se fosse uma linha só. Se você quiser garantir que as quebras de linha estejam no formato do seu sistema atual, é melhor usar [a propriedade de sistema](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) `"line.separator"`:

```
String quebraLinha = System.getProperty("line.separator"); // "\n" no Linux, 
                                                           // "\r\n" no Windows
                                                           // "\r" em algumas versões do Mac
```

Comment: Seria vantajoso então sempre usar `\r\n`, para que um arquivo se apresentasse da mesma forma em todos os três sistemas?

Comment: @Renan Até onde eu saiba, não há nenhum "efeito colateral" em se ter `\r` sobrando no Linux ou `\n` sobrando no Mac, mas creio que isso depende da aplicação (ex.: editor de texto específico, programa que vai processar o texto, etc). Imagino que se o texto é para consumo humano, usar `\r\n` seria o ideal - pois asseguraria que a grande maioria dos sistemas reconhecesse as quebras de linha e não "sobrasse" nada (muitos programas são robustos o suficiente para tratar de duas ou mais variações de quebra de linha na entrada).

Answer (score 16):

Nem toda a plataforma usa `"\n"` como separador de linhas. Exemplo:

Linux: `"\n"`
Windows: `"\r\n"`
Alguns Macs: `"\r"`

Então uma forma de saber qual o separador de linha da plataforma atual é a seguinte:

```
System.getProperty("line.separator"); // Anterior ao Java 7
System.lineSeparator();               // A partir do Java 7
```

<sub>Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383580/java-end-of-line-with-system-out-print</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Esta pergunta já tem algumas respostas bem interessantes, mas entendo que a pergunta não é sobre como usar a quebra de linha e sim sobre os **possíveis problemas**.

Bem, vou citar dois pelos quais já passei:

- Servidor linux usando `System.getProperty("line.separator")` gera arquivo texto com `\n`, mas o cliente abre no Bloco de Notas e reclama que o arquivo está "desformatado".
- Ao importar/exportar arquivos texto de/para outros sistemas deve-se definir um padrão independente do SO para evitar incompatibilidades.

**Lição: em sistemas web, *não* podemos confiar na propriedade de sistema**.

A solução na maioria desses casos é deixar a quebra *hard-coded* no código.

Pessoalmente, eu prefiro deixar `\r\n` porque funciona no Windows, sistema que a maioria dos usuários usa. Usuários de Linux e Mac geralmente usam editores mais avançados que iriam reconhecer as quebras de linha diferentes do SO.

Answer (score 3):

Como outros já disseram, não são todas as sistemas que interpretam o `End Of Line` igualmente. Por exemplo, uma vez meu arquivo `hosts` no Windows tinha, de um jeito ou outro, se salvada com `\n` e não `\r\n`. O que aconteceu foi que o Windows não conseguiu enteder o arquivo e fez com que nenhuma entrada do arquivo foi reconhecida (por `ping`, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

No caso do PHP, temos uma constante `PHP_EOL` que significa quebra de linha, pois para alguns sistemas o certo é quebrar linhas com `\r\n` e em outros sistemas é simplesmente `\n`.

No caso do Perl, existe o método `say` que nada mais é do que um `echo` com uma quebra de linha ao final. Acredito que o caractere de quebra de linha, nesse caso, também varie de sistema para sistema (apesar do Perl ser uma linguagem feita para funcionar principalmente em sistemas UNIX).

Provavelmente o Java possui algum caractere ou workaround para não ter que usar diretamente `\n` ou `\r\n`.