# Separar cada número com ponto e vírgula(;) no Java

Tags: java

Em uma caixa de texto que tem o nome da variável `MMdados` eu coloquei os números: `0;1;0`

Depois criei uma variável `String recebeMM` que recebe `MMdados.getText();`

Eu envio esses números para um campo de texto que tem o nome da variável MM fazendo que estes números fiquem um de baixo do outro.

Acaba imprimindo assim:

```
0
;
1
;
0
```

O meu problema é que o `;` tem que separar os números e não aparecer e não pode entrar na contagem do tamanho do `recebeMM.length()` no `for`.

Código:

```
private void BenviarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

    String recebeMM;

    recebeMM = MMdados.getText();

    String texto = "";

    recebeMM.split ("[;]");

    for(int i = 0; i < recebeMM.length(); i++){


        if(recebeMM != " "){ 


            texto = texto + recebeMM.charAt(i) + "\n";

        }

        MM.setText(texto);
    }

}
```

Usei o `recebeMM.split ("[;]");`. Porém não deu certo.

Answer (score 7):

[`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) recebe mesmo uma expressão regular e a sua não está errada, já que `[]` combina um único caracter do contido em `[]`, por exemplo para `[abc]` irá combinar apenas `a`, `b`, ou `c`. No seu caso tanto faz usar `;` ou `[;]`.

Assumindo que você precise, a partir da entrada `0;1;0`, de um resultado como este:

```
0
1
0
```

O seu problema está basicamente na forma com que está recuperando os valores depois do `split`. Este método retorna um vetor de caracteres, então você precisa atribuir este resultado a uma variável qualquer, por exemplo da seguinte forma:

```
final String[] values = recebeMM.split("[;]");
```

Depois disto, no `for`, ao invés de iteramos os caracteres de `recebeMM` iremos iterar o vetor resultado do `split`. Podemos usar um *enhaced for* , algo desta forma:

```
for (final String value : values) {
    if (value.trim().length() > 0) {
        texto.append(value);
        texto.append("\n\r");
    }
}
```

Ou o `for` padrão, algo assim:

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i ++) {
    final String value = values[i];
    if (value.trim().length() > 0) {
        texto.append(value);
        texto.append("\n\r");
    }
}
```

Observe também este trecho:

```
if(recebeMM != " ")
```

Bom, isto sempre será `true`, já que `recebeMM` é `0;1;0`, então a única coisa que você está fazendo é pegando caracter por caracter, incluindo um `\n` entre eles e informando como texto de `MM`.

Uma forma de usar o `charAt` como você usou seria mais ou menos isto, então não precisariamos do `split`:

```
final int length = recebeMM.length();
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    final char value = recebeMM.charAt(i);
    if (value != ' ' && value != ';') {
        texto.append(value);
        texto.append("\n\r");
    }
}
```

Outra coisa é que você deve fazer o *retorno do carro*, utilizando `\r` quando está atribuindo o valor a um `JTextField`, por exemplo, do contrário o resultado será algo como `0 1 0` ao fazer um `MM.getText()`. Para isto, basta usar `\n\r` no lugar de apenas `\n`.

Por último uma dica: considere sempre usar [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) (ou até mesmo [`StringBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html), dependendo do contexto) ao invés de concatenar *strings*.

Uma versão para o seu método `BenviarActionPerformed` seria esta:

```
private void BenviarActionPerformed(final java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    final String recebeMM = MMdados.getText();

    final StringBuilder texto = new StringBuilder();
    final String[] values = recebeMM.split("[;]");

    for (final String value : values) {
        if (value.trim().length() > 0) {
            texto.append(value);
            texto.append("\n\r");
        }
    }

    MM.setText(texto.toString());
}
```

Comment: Bruno só uma nota, isto está errado o carro sempre deve vir antes da quebra, ao invés de `\n\r` use `\r\n`.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Desse jeito deu certo, porém para eu continuar com o trabalho que é um simulador cache. Este método eu nunca tinha visto. Quer disser que value recebe cada número ou todos juntos ?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento na verdade não está errado, o padrão é mesmo fazer o retorno de carro antes, no entanto `setText` e `getText` tratam diferente seu conteúdo (basta ver na implementação). Teste imprimindo os valores diretamente (`System.out.println(texto.toString());`) e recuperando de um `JTextField` (`System.out.println(MM.getText());`) e verá a diferença, recuperando do `JTextField` ficará um espaço antes, isto é devido como os valores são tratados lá :)

Comment: @Diego não entendi, você diz a forma usando `charAt`? Se for ele recupera um caractere por vez e trata ele, já usando `split` temos um vetor de `String`, o resultado final é o mesmo, o valor de `texto`, inclui as duas porque pode ser que você estava tentando algo que não incluiu na questão :)

Comment: @BrunoCésar então está resposta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/7453/3635 estaria parcialmente incorreta?

Comment: Era usando o chaAt mas se no seu caso sendo o resultado o mesmo não tem problemas. Tenho que pegar cada posição de uma letra e converter para binário e colocar o bit de validação, depois vou pegar o número e fazer calculo com ele. No caso esta assim:         int bitvalidacao = 1; for (final String value : values){
if (value.trim().length() > 0){
bin = toBinaryString (cont);
int numero;
numero = Integer.parseInt(value);  texto.append(value +"----" +bin +"----" +bitvalidacao +"----" +numero);
          texto.append("\n\r");}
               MM.setText(texto.toString());
        }

Comment: @Diego http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3918/3635

Comment: @Diego então é isso aí mesmo, só continuar seu trabalho. Quaisquer outras dúvidas basta incluir novas questões

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não está errada esta reposta que linkou, como disse alguns componentes do swing tratam diferente o texto, nem se usa estes marcadores em swing. Como a questão aqui não é ser muito extenso coloquei para gerar o resultado que o AP espera. Qualquer coisa olhe a implementação dos métodos que citei ou me chame no chat que te dou mais detalhes, OK?

Answer (score 2):

Você tem um array qualquer: `list`

Basta fazer:

```
String myJoinedString = Joiner.on(";").join(list);
```

Esse código "junta" os elementos do seu `list` com o separador `;`

**EDIT:** Com esse código, o Joiner não deixa "sobrando" um separador no final, e pode-se substituir por quebra de linha ou outra coisa que for necessário no lugar do ;