# Angular ignora a quebra de linha no String

Tags: html, angular, unicode

Estou montando uma mensagem com varias mensagem em JAVA. Apos montada envio para o front/view porém o angular esta comendo todas as quebras de linhas:

```
public String salvarPorXLS(){

while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
    pErrors += "\n"+"Atividade do processo: " + numeroProcesso + " cadastrada com sucesso"+"\n";
}

return pErrors;
}
```

**Mensagem:**

> Atividade do processo: 00003362920178178224 cadastrada com sucesso
>   Atividade do processo: 00003362920178178224 cadastrada com sucesso
>   Atividade do processo: 00032906420158172001 cadastrada com sucesso
>   Atividade do processo: 00032906420158172001 cadastrada com sucesso
>   Atividade do processo: 00032906420158172001

Não esta quebrando a linha apos a palavra sucesso!

o angular esta atrapalhando o saida:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Nem dá pra testar esse código, então não tem como nem analisar nada. Mas testando no ideone, modificando algumas variaveis, funcionou perfeitamente: https://ideone.com/wVMQBD

Comment: Vê se isso te ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7448/usando-quebra-de-linha-n-no-java

Comment: O angular esta atrapalhando na saida da mensagem

Comment: vou acrescentar o codigo em html

Comment: O angular esta comendo a quebra de linha. O java esta certo!

Comment: Então edita a pergunta, porque sua duvida não tem a ver com java.

Comment: @jsbueno eu removi a tag java pq a duvida não tinha a ver com java, como o autor mesmo explicou nos comentários.

Comment: mas se você achava que seu problema estava no Java, o trechinho de código que está aí é do código em Java, ach que faz sentido. 
Por que se for por aí, também não tem nada a ver com "angular" - a dúvida é só da saída de texto  - terminal (ou arquivo texto) x html.

E na verdade, tem 0 de especificidades do Ângular na pergunta e na resposta, mas alem do código Java na pergunta, eu endereço Java na resposta aceita (mas o que comentei também vale para C, C#, CPP, avascript, Python e Ruby, pelo menos: linguagens que usam a sintaxe de escape de carácteres do C)

Comment: @jsbueno concordo com você, o autor é que não soube expressar direito sua duvida na pergunta. A duvida, no fim, não é nem de java e nem de angular.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se a saída é em html, então o `\n` não é uma quebra de linha - em html, um  caracter `\n` é umcracter de espaço em branco (whitespace) como o espaço (`\x20`) e tab (`\t`) .

Se  a sua saída é em HTML, você deveria estar colocando cada mensagem em um elemento semântico apropriado - usando as regras do seu framework para isso. Se a sua string vai ser usada como HTML direto, em vez de ser processada pelo Framework em um template, você poderia por exemplo, colocar os erros dentro de elementos `<li>...</li>`, e tudo dentro de um `<ul>...</ul>`.

Ou, a forma "rápida e barata", use um `<br>` onde está colocando `\n`.
Outra forma, é manter a saída como está, e mudar o estilo (CSS)  de apresentação da página - use CSS para que o elemento HTML que for apresentar o bloco das suas mensagens de erro trate `\n` como uma quebra de linha - isso pode ser feito colocando [a propriedade `white-space: pre-line;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) no elemento apropriado, por exemplo. (dica do @fernandosavio)

A propósito, `\n` não é nada "mágico" - é apenas o carácter de linefeed, de código decimal 16 (0x10) - e o escape `\n` para representa-lo é herdado da linguagem C - entre outras coisas, a única coisa que você ganha escrevendo algo como `"\n" + "minha frase"` em vez de simplesmente `"\nminha frase"` é digitar uma porção de coisas a mais - não há a menor necessidade disso.

Comment: A solução foi inserir o a tag <br> dentro da string

Comment: Vale acrescentar outra forma "rápida e barata": usando a propriedade CSS [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).